# In Haskell, how do I return the number of nodes in a binary tree?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Define, for a binary tree type Tree, a function which returns the number of nodes. I came up with this function but it does not run.

Error: Not in scope: data constructor'Node'

```
numberOfNodes :: Tree -> Int
numberOfNodes Null = 0
numberOfNodes (Node _ st1 st2) = 1 + max (st1)(st2)
```

Comment: Well apparently there's an error in you `Tree` definition as this function is unaware of `Node`.

Comment: Next issue: you don't want the maximum between the two subtrees, but the maximum of their number fo nodes.

Comment: You here calculated the *height* not the number of nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is that you appear to be missing a definition for what a Tree is.

Generally we say it's either a Node with a value plus two subtrees, or it's empty.

Next, our recursive definition for the number of nodes in a (non-empty) tree should be:

`number of nodes in left subtree` + `number of nodes in right subtree` + 1

Here is a full definition:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)
numberOfNodes :: Tree x -> Int
numberOfNodes Empty = 0
numberOfNodes (Node _ st1 st2) = 1 + numberOfNodes(st1) + numberOfNodes(st2)
```

(Note that we implement the `Show` typeclass so  that we can print the tree)

If we define a binary tree with 3 nodes, see how it works:

```
myTree :: Tree Int
myTree =
   Node 0
      (Node 1 Empty Empty)
      (Node 2 Empty Empty)
```

> `> numberOfNodes myTree` 
>   `=> 3`

#### [Live Demo](https://repl.it/repls/WateryUnripeVirtualmemory)

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that you did not make a data constructor `Node`. Perhaps you made a data constructor `Tree`, for example:

```
data Tree a = Null | Tree a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

using `Tree` as a data constructor is not *wrong*. But you need to decide what the name will be, and use that data constructor.

Anyway, you do not need to define a function to count the number of elements yourself. You can let Haskell make it an instance of `Foldable`, and then use [**`length :: Foldable f => f a -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Tree a = Null | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Foldable, Show)
```

If we for example define a [sample tree like @AndyG wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61322434/67579), we can calculate the number of `Node`s as:

```
Prelude> length (Node 0 (Node 1 Null Null) (Node 2 Null Null))
3
```

If you implement the length yourself, you should make a *recursive* call to the subtrees, since you can not add up subtrees:

```
numberOfNodes :: Tree -> Int
numberOfNodes Null = 0
numberOfNodes (Node _ st1 st2) = 1 + numberOfNodes st1 + numberOfNodes st2
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have the data type definition in scope. It should probably be

```
data Tree a = Null | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Also, the code you show computes a tree's depth <sup>(in principle, after it's fixed)</sup>. The total count of tree's nodes is the *sum* of the counts of nodes in its left and right sub-trees, give or take 1; not *max*.

Empty (leaf, `Null`) nodes should probably not be counted, i.e. their contribution to the total count should probably be 0. You decide.